# Socket always timing out in the end

Tags: java, sockets, exception, timeout

I have a code where I need to capture some information from a equipment. This equipment have a socket connection. Basically is this:

I send a command a have this returned:

```
<some info>
<some info>
<some info>
<some info>

1.551
1.689
... (A bunch of those numbers)
1.258

<more info>
```

I need part of the  but  is trash for me.

Fisrt Attempt was:

```
read <somne info>
reached empty line?
start getting the points
reached the points total amount?
break the loop
```

This kind of work. Sometimes for some reason, the next read I do on the socket (sending a command and expecting a single line answer) gives me some trash from this socket read. Bu just sometimes.

I tried to do this:

```
read <somne info>
reached empty line?
while !EOF
    is number?
    read
end
```

So. This read everything I need. But when reaches the end gives me a IOException: red timeout

I know there's nothing left for reading, so How could I avoid that?

Sorry, I don't have the actual code right no with me, but basically this is the problem: getting a exception with read timeout in the end of this loop:

```
while((line = readLine()) != null){
      //read stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy solution for this problem.

What I did was to insert a try/catch block inside reading block. So, When I finish reading the points, I go to that try/catch block which reads until EOF. Since there's no EOF, it throws an IOExcpetion (Read Timeout) witch I cactch, ignored it. And go on.

I know it's not the best solution, but s what is working right now.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing left for reading, the peer should have closed the connection. Then you will get your null and you can close your end. If the peer isn't doing that and the timeout is long enough for you to be confident there is no more data, the timeout is your evidence of that, and you neither can nor want to avoid it.

Comment: Ok. Let's suposse I decide to finish reading on timeout. I get an IOException, how could I chack that htis IOexception is for timeout?

Comment: @Rockskull Catch `SocketTimeoutException.`

Comment: I'll give it a try, but according with the Java Docs, SocketTimeoutException is thrown with connect method.